# Open and Collapse not working, after adding class active open

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I working on **[Bootstrap ClipOne Theme](http://themeforest.net/item/clipone-bootstrap-3-responsive-admin-template/full_screen_preview/5881143)**.

i just implement simple code to add **active & open** class for selected **li** but Problem is that when i click on Left Side Menu **Layout Link** open or collapse feature not working.

Here is my code

```
$('ul.main-navigation-menu li a').click(function () {
    $('ul.main-navigation-menu li').removeClass('active open');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active open');
});
```

Please help me..